# Unexpected space created at bottom of detail band contains list component

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a layout that have multiple subreports as section. (created by Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.2)
Subreport placed at main-report's detail band.

Report output works fine, but a problem occur about detail band height.

If my list row height is **Mpx** and row count is **N**, unexpected space [**M * (N-1) px**] is printed at bottom of detail band.

My subreport's spec overview is in below figs.

[image: capture of section when row size is 6]
*fig.1* a capture of section when list size is 6

[image: capture of section when row size is 7]
*fig.2* a capture of other section when list size is 7

Anyone know how to fix this ?
thanks.

**Update:**

Library version upadte from
`net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.2.2`
to
`net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.3.0`
, but has not resolved.

Comment: How much white space is left under either the lower left or lower right fixed heigt frame?

Comment: @tobi6 in my jrxml, spaces between **lower left frame** and **detail band's bottom** is **168px**, and between **lower right frame** and **detail band's bottom** is **0px**.

Comment: Maybe because of `Split type prevent` it tries to keep also the white space (168px) in the report?

Comment: @tobi6 I tried to change detail band 1 `Split Type` : `null`, `stretch`, `immediate`. but all of them does not work. anyway, thanks.